# Observable<any> as input parameter in child component

Tags: angular, datatables, observable

Depending the button clicked I load a different Observable.

In the parent component I have this :

```
<button (click)="onClickMe1()">Click me 1!</button>
<button (click)="onClickMe2()">Click me 2!</button>
```

but nothing is loaded in the table.

```
myDatasource : Observable<any>;
export class ClickMeComponent {
  onClickMe1() {
    this.myDatasource = this.invoiceService.getMyList1(); //return an Observable<any>
  }

  onClickMe2() {
    this.myDatasource = this.invoiceService.getMyList2(); //return an Observable<any>
  }
}

The child component :
<app-grid-invoice-basic-detail [datasource]=myDatasource></app-grid-invoice-basic-detail>


@Input() datasource: Observable<any[]>;
export class ChildComponent {

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        this.datasource.subscribe((data) => {
            this.dataTable = {
            headerRow: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
            footerRow: [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
            dataRows: data["invoices"]
        };
        this.InitTable();
        },
        error => {
        });     
    }

    InitTable(){
        $('#datatableBalanceAmount').DataTable({
          "lengthMenu": [
            [15, 30, 50, -1],
            [15, 30, 50, "All"]
          ],
          responsive: true,
          language: {
            search: '_INPUT_'
          }

        });     
    }
}
```

Update1, partial code of parent component

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="myTab1">
   <app-clickme [datasource]=tabLateInvoiceObservable></app-clickme>
</div>
```

Update2, JSON content :

```
{
    "invoices": [
        {
            "customerName": "XXXXXX",
            "customerReference": "1900008"
        }
    ]
}
```

didn't put all the fields here. But the return is correct because when I create the grid in the parent component, the values are visible and the grid too.

Comment: Could you show how did you use your ClickMeComponent together with the `app-grid-invoice-basic-detail` component?

Comment: your `@Input` decorator accepts `Observable<any[]>` where as you are passing `myDatasource` as `myDatasource : Observable<any>;` it won't work . It has to be type of `Observable<any[]>`

Comment: Can you post the JSON structure of `this.invoiceService.getMyList1();` response when you subscribe on it

Comment: The structure of this feels off. You should only really subscribe to the datasource Observable in ngOnInit, and have that same Observable emit different values depending on what is clicked. Why not create a Subject which will emit the appropriate values on each click, and export it as an Observable?

Answer (score 0):

Your component not implements ngOnChanges, but I suggest you use a setter and susbcribe inside this function, see an e.g. in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plggjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
@Input('data') 
  set $data(value)
  {
    if (value)
    value.subscribe(res=>{
      this.data=res
    })
  }
  data;
```

Comment: It's not what I'm trying to do. I use http client, then Observable and a parent component with a child.

Comment: @Kris-I Because you are changing the reference of your observable in the parent component, you need to notify the child about this change. Having setter is a way to do that.